# Dropbox OS X SDK: Multiple users simultaneously logged in

Tags: objective-c, macos, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have built iOS app that can be logged into multiple Dropbox accounts simultaneously using the Dropbox iOS SDK.

I am building an OS X companion app, but when using Dropbox's OS X SDK, I have not been able to show the log in screen when I am already logged in one account. The error message I get is

`[ERROR] DropboxSDK: called -[DBAuthHelperOSX authenticate] when already linked. Doing nothing.`

I thought at first it was because I was using `[DBAuthHelperOSX sharedHelper]` but it turned out even if I allocated/initialized my DBAuthHelperOSX object myself it still returned that error when I went to call `authenticate` the second time.

I then went to download the Dropbox OS X SDK from Dropbox's website so I could check out the implementation files of the `DBAuthHelperOSX` to see what is happening in `authenticate` to stop me, and it seems that `[[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]` is checked, and if it is is Linked, it throws that error. I tried commenting out that portion of the if statements, but afterwards if I try to call `authenticate` Dropbox throws me an error 401 : `"Invalid signature."`

Here is the link to where you can download the OS X SDK, and maybe someone can tell where I am creating the invalid signature when I try to log in with a second account:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/osx

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the Dropbox OS X Core SDK doesn't currently officially support multiple accounts (hence the isLinked check) but I'll be sure to pass this along as a request.

Comment: Thanks @Greg for the quick reply! I appreciate you taking the time checking this out. Is there a way I can craft my own URL so that it will work like the iOS SDK in the mean time? Thanks!

Comment: The SDK uses the HTTP endpoints here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs You can also integrate directly against those if you want, instead of using the SDK, though it would be a bit more work.